# C++ & proper TDD

Tags: c#, c++, performance, tdd

*Hi! I recently tried developing a small-sized project in `C#` and during the whole project our team used the Test-Driven-Development (`TDD`) technique (`xunit, moq`).*

I really think this was awesome, because (when paired with `C#`) this approach allowed to relax when coding, relax when projecting and relax when refactoring. I suspect that all this `TDD`-stuff actually simplifies the coding process and, well, it allowed (eventually, for me) to get the same result with fewer brain cells working.

Right after that I tried using `TDD` paired with `C++` (I used `Google Test` and `Google Mock` libraries), and, I don't know why but I actually think that TDD here was a step back in terms of rapid application development.

I had some moments when I had to spend huge amounts of time thinking of my tests, building proper mocks, rebuilding them and swearing at my monitor.

And, well, I obviously can't ask something like "what I did wrong?" or "what was wrong in my approach?", because I don't know what to describe. But if there are any people who are used to `TDD` in `C++` (and, probably `C#`) too, could you please advise me how to do this properly.

*Framework recommendations, architecture approaches, plain coding advices - if you are experienced in `TDD & C++`, please respond.*

Comment: Can you describe what are the most annoying differences between the setup you used for C#, and setup of C++ & gmoc & gtest? I have used gmock+gtest for TDD in C++ and I can't see any deficiencies of this tools, but then I haven't used xunit + moq in C# (hell, I haven't programmed that much in C#), so I might not know what I'm missing.

Comment: Well, I think that `jalf` actually wrote my opinion. I can't explain this in words better than he did, but when you code in C# and write all that interface stuff and so on it looks pretty `native`. When you try to do the same in C++ it starts to look like you're trying to force yourself to use something really outlandish. Maybe it's just about experience and getting used to think in the right way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think TDD is much harder to do in C++ than C#. The lack of reflection, and the common (and often well-justified) reluctance to rely on dynamic polymorphism (interfaces and in heritance) compared to static polymorphism does make it harder to mock out many classes.

There are some extremely clever unit test frameworks for C++, but the thing that's so clever about them is mainly that they try to bypass the language limitations.

TDD works best in dynamic languages. It's a great way to work in Python. It's doable in C# (which isn't dynamic, but has comprehensive reflection capabilities)

In C++, it's often problematic. That doesn't mean it can't, or shouldn't, be done, but when you do it, expect to have to work a bit harder at it. And sometimes,  you may be better off using another approach entirely.

Answer (score 4):

TDD is something that takes some practice to get right, regardless of the platform.  What some people don't seem to realize is that the nature of the problem your trying to solve can have a big impact on how easily you can apply TDD to the solution.  I've had problems in the past where I knew the solution I wanted to move towards, but it was extremely difficult to figure out how to break the problem up in a way that seemed to fit the TDD model.  Now there are several reasons why this may happen, and it's impossible to say what the "right" way to handle that situation is.

At this point my first reaction to running into this sort of problem is to re-examine my original assumptions about the problem.  Am I making it more complex than it needs to be?  Am I trying to write tests to arrive at a design I've already decided on instead of letting the tests guide the design?  Is it just a funky problem, and I need to accept that the typical TDD approach isn't going to work in this case?

For an interesting discussion of this you can look at [this blog post](http://blog.objectmentor.com/articles/2009/10/06/echoes-from-the-stone-age) from Uncle Bob Martin, where he talks about an attempt by Ron Jeffries to [create a Sudoku Solver using TDD](http://xprogramming.com/articles/oksudoku/), and it doesn't really work.  Now because this attempt did not produce a good solution doesn't mean that TDD is useless, it just means that the problem being solved is more complex, and does not lend itself to the emergent design approach of TDD.

Answer (score 2):

Try the easiest - [CxxTest](http://cxxtest.sourceforge.net/guide.html).

Answer (score 1):

I find test driven development very hard to do properly all the time; sometimes the tests just flow, sometimes a bit of a jump is required. To keep things fast I frequently step away from the TDD approach. That isn't a problem for me as I maintain a full set of unit tests for all the code I've 'completed' (allowing the relaxation while coding the new bits and refactoring) .